# gridView update after left row

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to handle event left row on grid View? I would like to make update in database after left row in grid view. When user enter data in text box in grid view he has to click save button.

I use grid on web page and I use .net 2.0

Comment: Is this the GridView in web forms that you are using?

Comment: Is it enough to trigger the save when they come out of the textbox?  Or do they need to be out of the row entirely before your save is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

If by left row event you mean unselecting then you can react on selectedindexchanged event and check if selected indedx is -1

Comment: Yes, I want make update after click in another row. User enter example price for item and go to next line without click save button, so use has to select another line. Can I get actually value from textbox (not binded from DB) ?

Comment: Ok, so it's not unselecting. There are two things that you should handle. First is RowCancelingEdit event on gridview. Second is RowEditing event also in datagrid. RowCancelingEdit is fired when user click cancel button. RowEditing event is a bit tricky because in this event you must check if EditIndex of you gridview is greater than -1. If it is then you know that last edited row was not saved and also you have an index of that row so you can get values.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do it.  You could wire up an event on the tab key or blur event for the last control of the grid row.  This means they've gotten to the last input, it does validation to make sure all the other required boxes are filled, and then it posts back the update, or you could add a focus event to controls in all rows in the gridview and keep track of which row they're on in that focus event.  If the row changes you fire an update for the last row index.

My preference is the second option.

*Edit: You could save yourself some trouble and use event bubbling by wiring up the focus on the table or table body and let the controls' focus event bubble up.